# What would be the best way to create a link to a specific part of a page (widget) in Google App Maker?

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I need to create a link (icon) in app maker that will jump to a specific part of the same page. The widget I am trying to link to is a simple horizontal panel with a label in it. Basically just creating a shortcut for a user to jump to a section lower down the page. I can figure out how to jump to a specific page in my app but not a specific position or widget on the same page?

Answer (score 1):

Can't believe I'm referring to HTML as a "lower level" of code, but, this is where we are. The HTML is simple - how you make this work using App Maker is up to you.  I know that App Maker will allow arbitrary HTML, so getting this to work shouldn't be too hard.

At the position on your page that you want the user to be able to jump to, you need to create an 'anchor tag' - which looks the same as any other anchor tag, except that it includes a 'name' instead of a url:

`<a name="jumpto"></a>`

Now, to create a link which will jump to 'jumpto' you create another anchor tag around your icon that will work like any other link, except that it will jump to the named location in your page instead of jumping to another site on the www:

`<a href="#jumpto">...</a>`

Replace the ellipses with your icon image / text / whatever and you'll be ready to go!